# How to manage Server side rendering, in Meteor environment with React, Material UI and Styled-components?

Tags: reactjs, meteor, material-ui, styled-components, server-side-rendering

I have implemented as explained in [Meteor docs](https://docs.meteor.com/packages/server-render.html). All my components css which I have added gets rendered. But Material UI components, look and feel is not as I have in client version.

I have tried this [MaterialUI Docs](https://material-ui.com/guides/server-rendering/#server-rendering), but no luck yet. Also I'm not using `react-jss`.

If anyone knows any example projects, which I could use, that would be really awesome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to this question is very simple, just follow docs in material ui & styled-components docs, and use functions implemented in both SSR topics.

Then you have style tags from material ui & styled-components working fine.
I have shown here the my **SSR** code, it follows how to do SSR render in meteor environment.

SSR implementation docs:

[Meteor docs with styled-components usage](https://docs.meteor.com/packages/server-render.html)

[MaterialUI docs](https://material-ui.com/guides/server-rendering/)

```
import React from 'react'
import { MuiThemeProvider, createMuiTheme, createGenerateClassName } from '@material-ui/core/styles'
import { SheetsRegistry } from 'react-jss/lib/jss'
import JssProvider from 'react-jss/lib/JssProvider'
import { renderToString } from 'react-dom/server'
import { onPageLoad } from 'meteor/server-render'
import { StaticRouter } from 'react-router'
import { Provider } from 'react-redux'
import { Helmet } from 'react-helmet'
import { ServerStyleSheet } from 'styled-components'
import MainApp from '../imports/app/MainApp'
import store from '../imports/app/store/store'

onPageLoad(sink => {
  const context = {}
  // Create a sheetsRegistry instance.
  const sheetsRegistry = new SheetsRegistry()

  // Create a sheetsManager instance.
  const sheetsManager = new Map()
  // Theme Font Change
  const theme = createMuiTheme({
    typography: {
      fontFamily: 'FuturaPT-Light',
      fontWeight: 'normal',
      fontStyle: 'normal',
    },
  })
  const generateClassName = createGenerateClassName()
  const sheet = new ServerStyleSheet()

  const App = () => (
    <Provider store={store}>
      <StaticRouter location={sink.request.url} context={context}>
        <JssProvider registry={sheetsRegistry} generateClassName={generateClassName}>
          <MuiThemeProvider theme={theme} sheetsManager={sheetsManager}>
            <MainApp />
          </MuiThemeProvider>
        </JssProvider>
      </StaticRouter>
    </Provider>
  )

  sheet.collectStyles(<App />)
  sink.renderIntoElementById('react-root', renderToString(<App />))
  const css = sheetsRegistry.toString()
  const helmet = Helmet.renderStatic()
  sink.appendToHead(helmet.meta.toString())
  sink.appendToHead(helmet.title.toString())
  sink.appendToHead(`<style id="jss-server-side">${css}</style>`) // material-ui css attached
  sink.appendToHead(sheet.getStyleTags()) // styled-components css attached

  // console.log(html)
  const preloadedState = store.getState()

  sink.appendToBody(
    `<div id="pre-loaded-state" style="display:none">${JSON.stringify(preloadedState).replace(
      /</g,
      '\\u003c'
    )}</div>`
  )
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Even though they use Bootstrap rather than Material UI, I recommend you to check this boilerplate, which manages SSR: [cleverbeagle pup](https://github.com/cleverbeagle/pup), which now uses Styled-components too. It will give you a good idea of how to achieve it, or you can try to migrate the css framework and components to Material UI.

Comment: thanks for your effort, but this won't solve, my problem. I tried it, it only shows SSR implementation with styled-components

Answer (score 0):

You can try the npm package [maka-cli](https://www.npmjs.com/package/maka-cli), and generate a boilerplate application with react, material-ui, and SSR and see how I did it:

`$ maka create NewApp --theme=material --ssr=true --client=react`

Then, navigate to the file:

`./NewApp/imports/startup/server/index.jsx`

and you can see how the app scaffolded out the material-ui with SSR.  Note, that this is not using the latest material-ui (1.0.0-beta.36) ... but it could be a start!

```
/************* SSR Code ********************/
import Routes from '../lib/routes.jsx';
import React from 'react';
import { renderToStaticMarkup } from 'react-dom/server';
import { onPageLoad } from 'meteor/server-render';
import { StaticRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import { createMemoryHistory } from 'history';


import { SheetsRegistry } from 'react-jss/lib/jss';
import JssProvider from 'react-jss/lib/JssProvider';
import { create } from 'jss';
import preset from 'jss-preset-default';
import { MuiThemeProvider, createMuiTheme } from 'material-ui/styles';
import createGenerateClassName from 'material-ui/styles/createGenerateClassName';
import { grey } from 'material-ui/colors';

onPageLoad(sink => {
    const history = createMemoryHistory(sink.request.url.pathname);
    const App = (props) => (
        <StaticRouter
            location={props.location}
            context={{}}>
            <Routes history={history}/>
        </StaticRouter>
    );
    // Create a sheetsRegistry instance.
    const sheetsRegistry = new SheetsRegistry();

    // Create a theme instance.
    const theme = createMuiTheme({
        palette: {
            primary: grey,
            accent: grey,
            type: 'light',
        },
    });

    const jss = create(preset());
    jss.options.createGenerateClassName = createGenerateClassName;

    const html = renderToStaticMarkup(
      <JssProvider registry={sheetsRegistry} jss={jss}>
        <MuiThemeProvider theme={theme} sheetsManager={new Map()}>
          <App location={sink.request.url} />
        </MuiThemeProvider>
      </JssProvider>
    );
    const css = sheetsRegistry.toString();
    sink.appendToHead(`<style id="jss-server-side">${css}</style>`);
    sink.renderIntoElementById('app', html);
});
```

Comment: Thanks for effort, but my question is how to get it working all together material ui & styled components in meteor environment.